# SSL error when redirecting from one lightsail subdomain to lightsail subdomain on different account

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I have a multi account setup in AWS

There is an administrative account where my domain is registered (example.com)
There is a production account using lightsail where my subdomain is registered (prod.example.com)
I am using a loadbalancer on lightsail production account

I want to point  app.example.com to app.prod.example.com and can set this up with a CNAME entry in the administrative account.

When I go to app.example.com I get a privacy error that states that "This server couldn't prove that it's app.example.com; its security certificate is from prod.example.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

I have an SSL certificate for example.com via R53 on my admin account.  I have SSL certificate from lightsail for the loadbalancer.

How do I ensure the link is trusted?

Added CNAME record in admin account pointing from app.example.com to app.prod.example.com